# Building a 32-bit app in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, gcc

After hours of googling, I decide to give up and ask you experts. I am trying to build a 32-bit application (xgap if anyone interested) in my 64 Ubuntu 11.10. I added the **CFLAGS=-m32** and the **LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib32** in the makefile. The objects are built into 32 bit fine. The last step is to link all the objects and libraries for X windows into this executable---xgap. Somehow it keeps giving me this error:

```
gcc -o xgap xcmds.o utils.o gapgraph.o gaptext.o pty.o popdial.o xgap.o selfile.o   -L/usr/lib32 -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lXext -lX11  -lSM -lICE

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/libXmu.so when searching for -lXmu
...

/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `xcmds.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
...
```

I have installed **ia32-libs** and **mutilib support**. I think I just need to force the linker to generate a i386 output. I tried to put two **ld** flags in my gcc command as shown above: **-melf_i386** and **-oformat elf32-i386**. But what happens is that gcc doesn't search for the 32 bit library in **/usr/lib32** anymore. I wonder if I need to put those flags in some fixed order?

Thanks for any idea and help!

EDIT: when I add the -m32 flag in my last gcc command (the linking stage I believe), even if I have the -L/usr/lib32 flag in place, gcc doesn't search in /usr/lib32 anymore ( really weird...) and generates the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXaw
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any one has any idea why this happens? I am using the auto tool to configure and make. I am really good at modifying those script files.

**EIDT**:I solved the problem. I think that **gcc** was expecting a static library archive. I used the **getlibs** script from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790 to download all the .a archives needed for linking. Then **gcc** worked. I think **gcc** did search in **/usr/lib32** directory but didn't find the  **.a** archives so went on to search in the standard directory which is **/usr/lib**, where it finds the incompatible ***.so** files.

But then the question is: the ***.so** files in **/usr/lib32/** from package **ia32-libs** doesn't really have the libraries needed for linking? What are those files in **/usr/lib32/** used for?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654288/how-to-make-compiler-generate-a-elf32-x86-64-format-object-file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`LDFLAGS` should include `-m32` as well. Following should work:

```
export LDFLAGS='-m32 -L/usr/lib32'
```

In fact, you can drop `-L/usr/lib32` part, since this is a default directory for 32bit libs, and your system is aware about that.

Basically, the simplest way to build 32bit application on 64bit machine is:

```
export CFLAGS='-m32'
export CXXFLAGS='-m32'
export LDFLAGS='-m32'
make
```

..or [feed those variables to configure script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-a-configure-script) if you're using autotools.

UPDATE:

Seems like you are not really familiar about the differences in linking with static and dynamic libraries. I'll try to be as minimal as possible:

- Both static and dynamic development libraries have the same file extension `.a`
- If you have installed both static and dynamic versions of the same library, one of them might have additional postfix, like `libname.a` for dynamic and `libname_s.a` for static version.
- Sure, static and dynamic library versions differs in size. Static version is heavier.
- If you link with static library - your application has no dependencies. If you link with dynamic library, it will rely on `.so` runtime library that should be present in your system.

Please note, we are not talking about advanced tricks here, like explicit loading of DSO's using the dlopen()/dlsym() API.

Comment: Now I think there is something wrong with my setup. Whenever I add the -m32 in my last gcc command, it searches /usr/lib folder instead. If I don't add -m32, and use -L/usr/lib32 flag, it searches the correct directory but generated the errors above. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: And what will happen if you combine both (as in my example above)?

Comment: if I combine both, it still doesn't search in /usr/lib32. it just searches in /usr/lib. And btw, I am using auto tools.

Comment: Weird.. Did you tried feeding `-l/usr/lib32/libXaw.so` instead?

Comment: It can't find them....:gcc -o xgap xcmds.o utils.o gapgraph.o gaptext.o pty.o popdial.o xgap.o selfile.o  -O2 -L/usr/lib32  -l/usr/lib32/libXaw.so -l/usr/lib32/libXmu.so -l/usr/lib32/libXt.so -l/usr/lib32/libXext.so -l/usr/lib32/libX11.so  -l/usr/lib32/libSM.so -l/usr/lib32/libICE.so -m32 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib32/libXaw.so

Comment: Hmm.. I think we went to a dead end here :) You should link with .a files, not with .so ones.

Comment: there is no static libs in /usr/lib32 for the various libs for my case.

Comment: I solved the problem and updated my original question. Thanks Andrejs!

Comment: Glad to hear! I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: I see. I thought the .so  files are those libraries for linking... yeah when I used the getlibs script, the .a files are downloaded. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks for the time save, all the files lined up through LD_DEBUG/`file`/`objdump`, and `-m32` was given to `make`, just to turn out that it was just a flag for the linker missing the whole time.

Answer (score 13):

I was getting errors such as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
```

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

if you are using a gcc package other than the default one (e.g. `gcc-7`), then you'll need to install the package for that specific version:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-7-multilib
```

Comment: `g++-multilib` is for g++ (C++), for gcc (C) you need also `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: This solved the problem for me using `gcc-10` and `g++-10` which need `gcc-10-multilib` and `g++-10-multilib`

Comment: For some reason, gcc-multilib did nothing for me. I have to still install gcc-<version>-multilib to get compiler/linker going. BTW, yes I have the proper version set as default for my environment.